# Set high score as elapsed time in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The high score in my game is time based and I am having trouble setting comparing it with the current score. This is my code so far which doesn't work:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

// initialise value for current time
var currentTime = NSDate()
var bestTime = NSDate()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    super.didMoveToView(view)

    // set the current time to 0 seconds
    var date0 = NSDate();
    let timeInterval = floor(date0 .timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate / 60.0) * 60.0
    date0 = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeInterval)

    currentTime = date0

    // call to start timer
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "printDuration:", userInfo: NSDate(), repeats: true)
```

Then

```
func printDuration(timer: NSTimer) {
    if self.view?.paused == false {
        guard let userInfo = timer.userInfo else {
            return
        }
        guard let startDate = userInfo as? NSDate else {
            return
        }

        let duration = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)
        currentTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: duration)
        currentTimeValueLabel.text = "\(NSString(format:"%3.2f", duration))"
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do something like below where I am able to compare the time in both variables and set the higher one accordingly:

```
if (currentTime > highScore) {
    highScore = currentTime
    highScoreLabel.text = "\(NSString(format:"%3.2f", highScore))"
}
```

Comment: What is happening when you try to run this code?

Comment: the value for date0 becomes: -1717426878592353655261912811698508826252890002504464699165846566428214862376509747970125945631185930038292799551885463919712101939824288132382948354109005732550749122382004224.00

Comment: Just save `startDate = NSDate()` when it starts and test `NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)`

Comment: Thanks, startDate becomes 0.000379025936126709 but how do I compare the two NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)?

Comment: This will give you a time interval (duration).

Comment: startDate won't be 0 it is a date (point in time)

Comment: would you be able to tell me how I go about pausing this if the app is sent to the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set startDate = NSDate() in didMoveToView() at the beginning and then compare the two to see if duration is higher by typing

```
if duration > highScore {
    highScore = duration
}
```

Comment: Having set 
    highscore = NSDate() 
and trying to do this comparison, I get the error "Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSInterval' (aka Double) and NSDate.

Comment: Is highscore supposed to be a length of time?

Comment: Yes, the longer the player last their high score becomes that length of time (5.01s)

Comment: Then you would not want high score to be NSDate(). You could either let swift figure out the type or explicitly set it to be an NSInterval.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!